# Get query part of URL

Tags: php, parsing

I have a page that can have a link to in either one of the formats below:

- http://mydomain.com/linkID
- http://mydomain.com/linkID?9c1023a67eaf46cae864a31097

When the query part of the URL is present, I need to capture it with PHP. I tried using **parse_url** but I'm not really sure how to use it. Tried this

```
echo (parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']['query']));
```

but it returns Array...

Comment: You can use `http_build_query` with $_GET variable.

Comment: Many solutions are provided below, but FYI, if you're debugging something and you get "Array" you need to use PRINT_R to see the contents of the array...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optional 2nd parameter of [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) allows you to specify precisely what portion of URL you need:

```
<?php
echo parse_url("http://mydomain.com/linkID", PHP_URL_QUERY); // <empty string>
echo parse_url("http://mydomain.com/linkID?9c1023a67eaf46cae864a31097", PHP_URL_QUERY); // 9c1023a67eaf46cae864a31097
```

On the other hand, it is easier to use a server variable, if applicable:

```
echo isset($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) ? $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] : "";
```

Answer (score 6):

You should do:

```
$parsed = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $parsed['query'];
```

**EDIT:**

If you only need the query part of the URL and nothing more the solution of Salman below is actually a bit nicer:

```
echo parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

This should be all you need. See [$_SERVER variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 1):

parse_url returns an associative array (aka hash, dictionary, etc.) with the following keys:

```
scheme - e.g. http
host
port
user
pass
path
query - after the question mark ?
fragment - after the hashmark #
```

which could break down something like this:

```
scheme   user    password   host              port path       query     fragment
[http]://[santa]:[password]@[www.website.com]:[80]/[page.php]?[var=val]#[anchor]
```

you appear to be looking for one of these:

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $parsedUrl['query'];
echo $_SERVER['query_string'];
```